# String does NOT equal to (string1 OR string 2 OR string 3) in java

Tags: java, string

How do I test if a string does not equal to string1 OR string2 OR string3? I tried using ||, but it doesn't work:

```
 if (!answer1.equals("s1" || "s2" || "s3")){
        System.out.println("...");
 }
```

Comment: You can't or strings.  So try `if (! (answer1.equals("s1") || answer1.equals("s2") || answer1.equals("s3"))) { System.out.println("..."); }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing is the "normal" way:

```
if (!(answer1.equals("s1") || answer1.equals("s2") || answer1.equals("s3"))) {
}
```

Some alternate approaches include string switch, on JDK7+:

```
switch (answer1) {
  case "s1":
  case "s2":
  case "s3":
    break;
  default:
    // whatever
}
```

...or:

```
if (!Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3").contains(answer1)) {
}
```

Comment: And if `answer1` is null?

Comment: @DavidWallace: if `answer1` is null, than a NullPointerException is thrown, as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Prebuild a `Set<String>` containing `"s1"`, `"s2"` etc, and then use `!set.contains(answer1)`.

Comment: Seems very unnecessary and expensive for such a trivial task.

Comment: @JamoBox, not if you build it once, when the class is loaded.  This is a really good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `answer1` to be `"s1"`, `"s2"` or `"s3"`, so you need to AND the comparisons like this:

```
if (!answer1.equals("s1") && !answer1.equals("s2") && !answer1.equals("s13"))
{
        System.out.println("...");
}
```

You can also try

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
if (!strings.contains(answer1))
{
    System.out.println("...");
}
```

Comment: I would probably use Sets in this case. They tend to implement `contains` method to work as fast as possible because they use is most often.

Comment: @Pshemo that would depend on the concrete implementation of Set. The advantage of using Sets is that they don't allow duplicates; with a list you could have been comparing to the same String multiple times. I used the list this way to create a smaller example, but following your advice, one can use: Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"));

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !( "s1".equals(answer1) || "s2".equals(answer1) || "s3".equals(answer1))) {
    // ... whatever
}
```

Comment: I think it's better practice to do `answer1.equals("string")` instead of `"string".equals(answer1)`

Comment: But writing `"string".equals(answer1)` is null-safe.  You don't have to check for nulls separately.  That's why people do it - it's better this way round.

Comment: Couldn't you still get a `NullPointerException` if `answer1` isn't resolved to a value?

Comment: @WOUNDED false. It's actually better to the the constant first as this will not throw an NPE if the variable is `null`.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones What do you mean "isn't resolved to a variable"?  `answer` _is_ a variable.

Comment: Well, only the OP can comment on what they _really_ want to happen if the variable is null.  But not running the code block, and not throwing an exception seems reasonable to me.  If an exception is to be thrown in this case, it might be better to make a custom exception, than to use the default NullPointerException - but doing that's an entirely different question.

Comment: @DavidWallace Retracted my comment because I did some research and it turns out that this is actually a coding standard. However, it looks like the standard has some opposition. Some purists call this an anti-pattern that, as I said in my earlier deleted comment, makes maintenance a nightmare. I also can't seem to retract my down vote because 5 minutes have elapsed. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are attemting to do an OR on two Strings. For an example, let me ask you a question: "s1" or "s2"? The answer: Who knows? What is the question even talking about? Let me try again: Is it equal to "s1"? (No.) Is it equal to "s2"? (No.) Is it equal to "s3"? (Yes.) etc... Thus:

```
if(!(answer1.equals("s1") || answer1.equals("s2") || answer.equals("s3")) ) { ... }
```

Attempting to do OR on strings is simply invalid; you have to do it in some form like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple alternative:

```
if (!"s1,s2,s3".contains(answer1))
```

Assumes that your answer doesn't contain a comma, and even then it would need to be an edge case to give a false positive.